# call a class in another class

Tags: php

Hi I have some problem to call a class in another class, below code the 1 is ok to show result, but in 2 use the same code add to another class, I don't know why it is not work.
Thanks.

1

```
require 'database.php';
$database = new Database();

$database->query('SELECT user_id, user_email FROM tb WHERE user_id = :user_id');
$database->bind(':user_id', '1');
$rows = $database->resultset(); // fetchall

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows);
echo "</pre>";
```

2

```
require 'database.php';
$database = new Database();

class test{
    public function testf(){
        print"log";
        $database->query('SELECT user_id, user_email FROM tb WHERE user_id = :user_id');
        $database->bind(':user_id', '1');
        $rows = $database->resultset(); // fetchall

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($rows);
        echo "</pre>";
        print"log";
    }
}
$foo = new test();
$foo -> testf();
```

Comment: Why isn't it working? What do you want this to accomplish? What have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `$database` is available only in the global scope - not in the scope of `test`. Change it to:

```
require 'database.php';
$database = new Database();

class test{
    public function testf($database){
        print"log";
        $database->query('SELECT user_id, user_email FROM tb WHERE user_id = :user_id');
        $database->bind(':user_id', '1');
        $rows = $database->resultset(); // fetchall

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($rows);
        echo "</pre>";
        print"log";
    }
}

$foo = new test();
$foo -> testf($database);
```

---

Another option is to have $database as a class variable (sounds better). Then do this:

```
class test {

    protected $database; 

    public function __construct() {
        $this->database = new Database();
    }


    public function testf(){
        print"log";
        $this->database->query('SELECT user_id, user_email FROM tb WHERE user_id = :user_id');
        $this->database->bind(':user_id', '1');
        $rows = $this->database->resultset(); // fetchall

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($rows);
        echo "</pre>";
        print"log";
    }   

}

$foo = new test();
$foo -> testf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    require 'database.php';


    class test{
var $database;
public function test(){
$database = new Database();
}
        public function testf(){
            print"log";
            $this->database->query('SELECT user_id, user_email FROM tb WHERE user_id = :user_id');
            $this->database->bind(':user_id', '1');
            $rows = $database->resultset(); // fetchall

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($rows);
            echo "</pre>";
            print"log";
        }
    }
    $foo = new test();
    $foo -> testf();
```